# Samsung galaxy j6 plus stolen, lockscreen bypass possible?

Tags: samsung

My phone was stolen and there is alot of sensitive data in it
There was a lock screen in pin format, it was not a third party app
There was not sd memory card
Developper mode was not enabled
The phone was not encrypted
Android was up to date
Can the thief access its contents like apps contents and pictures ?
Thanks alot

Comment: *"phone was not encrypted"* is contradictory with Android 8.1 (Oreo) can't be true. have you unlocked bootloader and modified your phone to remove encryption? if it is a 5 digit pin your data is safe for a week. the only access is incoming calls and notifications. if your SIM card has no own pin protection it can be misused. btw normal thief usually is not interested in your data. check [Find My Mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) or [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) there you can remote erase (if not visible device is most likely factory reset already)